# hierarchal zero-to-one relationship in fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I'm somewhat new to nHibernate, especially fluent, and I'm having trouble with mapping a relationship where class `A` extends class `B`, but it isn't guaranteed that a given `A` is also a `B`. Here's an idea of what the structure looks like so far (and it's open to suggestion):

```
public class User
{
    public virtual Guid Id;
    public virtual string UserName;
    public virtual string HashedPassword;
    //...
}

public class Student : User
{
    public virtual Guid UserId;
    public virtual School School;
    public virtual float GPA;
}

public class Teacher : User
{
    public virtual Guid UserId;
    public virtual School School;
    public virtual string ClassName;
}
```

So I want to have `Teacher` and `Student` objects that I can work with, but I also want to be able to keep track of them for membership validation (hence the `User` base class).

So two questions:

1. Is this a reasonable way to do what I'm trying to do?
2. If so, how can this be mapped using Fluent nHibernate?

Comment: why is User a base class instead of an interface? it looks strange to see 2 Ids on the same class (Id and UserId)#

Comment: @Firo yeah I actually since made it an abstract class (cuz I want to keep the membership logic there) and took out the UserIds on the sublasses (which I only put there because I thought NHibernate was going to need it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Table("Users");

        Id(x => x.Id);

        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.HashedPassword);
    }
}
public class StudentMap : SubclassMap<Student>
{
    public StudentMap()
    {
        Table("Students");

        References(x => x.School);
        Map(x => x.GPA);
    }
}
public class TeacherMap : SubclassMap<Teacher>
...
```

tables

```
Users (
    Id,        // PK
    Name,
    HashedPassword
)
Students (
    User_Id,        // PK, FK
    School_id,
    Gpa
)
```

### Option 2

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Table("Users");
        DiscriminateSubclassesOnColumn("UserType", "user");

        Id(x => x.Id);

        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.HashedPassword);
    }
}
public class StudentMap : SubclassMap<Student>
{
    public StudentMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue("student");

        References(x => x.School);
        Map(x => x.GPA);
    }
}
public class TeacherMap : SubclassMap<Teacher>
...
```

tables

```
Users (
    Id,        // PK
    UserType,
    Name,
    HashedPassword
    School_id,
    Gpa
    Classname
)
```

### Option 3

```
public abstract class UserMap<TUser> : ClassMap<TUser> where TUser : User
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);

        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.HashedPassword);
    }
}
public class StudentMap : UserMap<Student>
{
    public StudentMap()
    {
        Table("Students");

        References(x => x.School);
        Map(x => x.GPA);
    }
}
public class TeacherMap : UserMap<Teacher>
...
```

tables

```
Students (
    Id,        // PK
    Name,
    HashedPassword
    School_id,
    Gpa
)
Teachers (
    Id,        // PK
    Name,
    HashedPassword
    School_id,
    Classname
)
```

Comment: I did some researching yesterday and ended up going with option 2. Nice answer!